# What is the word to convey the same meaning as the replacement money?

Tags: word-choice

Consider the following scenario.

> I go to a shop and buy many electronic components using my own money. Later, the company will give me money with the same amount as a replacement.

What is the Japanese noun to describe this replacement money?

I found a word 再調達原価{さいちょうたつげんか} but it means replacement cost rather than replacement money.

Applying it in a sentence:

> 会社が再調達原価としてお金をくれます。
>
> The company will give me money as the replacement cost.

But I actually want to say

> The company will give me money as the replacement money.

## Edit

Probably the following conversation might make it easier to understand.

> ボス：どうぞ。(The boss gives me money)
>
> 私：このお金は何ですか。(I pretend I don't understand what that money is for)
>
> ボス：（Replacement money） です。(The boss explains that that money is given as a replacement money)
>
> 私：ありがとうございます。(I thank the boss as a closing word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

精算{せいさん} is the word. It means to calculate how much you lend/borrow and to make it even.

> 店に行って、(会社用の) 電気部品をたくさん購入し、代金は私が立て替えておいた。後で、会社で立て替えた代金を精算した。

立{た}て替{か}える means to pay for someone, expecting that person will repay.

Comment: But it does not convey the meaning of replacement money.

Comment: You can say 精算金.

Comment: How about 弁償金 ?

Comment: 弁償 is 'compensation for damage'.

Comment: でも、「どうぞ。」「このお金は何ですか？」「清算金です。」「ありがとうございます。」という会話にはならないでしょう？「どうぞ。」「このお金は何ですか？」「この前立て替えておいてくれた分です。」とか「立て替えておいてくれた部品の代金です。」とかいうふうに言いませんか？

Comment: @choco そうですね、精算金と言う言葉は会計処理 (accounting) で使われることはあっても、日常会話で使うことはありませんね。おっしゃるとおり、replacement money に当たる言葉を使わないのが、日本語として自然だと思います。

Comment: とすると、単純に「立替え分」と言い換えられるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are asking for the Japanese equivalent of "reimbursement."
"返金" is the word that I would use, but it may be closer to "refund" than "reimbursement."